# Asking for user's input inside a while loop in javaScript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm creating a number guessing game in JavaScript. I'm using the input.value property to get user input. Now I have a while loop which should execute until the number entered by user is equal to the actual number. But I'm unable to get out of loop and ask for user input again as the while loop always evaluates to true. How can I ask for user's input again. Please suggest anything else rather than using prompt.

```
        var correctNumber = 16
        function answer() {
            while (inputNumber !== correctNumber) {
                var inputNumber = Number(inputValue.value)
                inputNumber = Number(inputValue.value)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why have a loop? Just have function return `false` and don't allow processing until it is correct. Also note anyone could view the source here and get the number. You could throw an error message on page or an `alert` to inform user there number was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <label for="answer">Your guess:</label>
    <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" />
    <button onclick="guessAnswer">Guess Answer</button>
    <p id="feedback"></p>
    
    <script>
    const correctNumber = 16;
    const feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');
    function guessAnswer() {
      const answer = document.getElementById('answer');
      if(answer == correctNumber) {
        feedback.innerHTML = 'Correct';
      } else {
        feedback.innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
      }
    }
    </script>
  <body>
</html>
```